# Storing data in array vs text file

Tags: powershell

My database migration automation script used to require the user to copy the database names into a text file, then the script would read in that text file and know which databases to migrate.

I now have a form where the user selects which databases to migrate, then my script automatically inserts those database names into the text file, then reads in that text file later in the script.

Would it be better practice to move away from the text file all together and just store the data in an array or some other structure?

I'm also using PowerShell.

Comment: What's provoking the question? Simple curiosity?

Comment: Yeah, I know both methods work. Was just curious as to which method is better and why.

Comment: I'd recommend de-coupling the input data format from the script or function. Rewrite the script/function to take the database names as a string array, then you can always do `.\MigrationScript.ps1 -DBName (Get-Content .\databasenames.txt)` when you have a text file and `.\MigrationScript.ps1 -DBName $array` when you have them in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on this, but I would suggest keeping the text file even if you choose to use the `array` or form only approach. You can keep the text file as sort of a log file, so you don't have to read from it, but you could write to it so you can quickly determine what databases were being migrated if an error happens.

Although in a production environment you probably have more sophisticated logging tools, but I say keep the file in case of an emergency and you have to debug.

When you finish migrating and determine in the script that everything is as it should be, then you can clear the text file or keep it, append the date and time, and store it, as a quick reference should another task come up and you need quick access to databases that were migrated on a certain date.